# Open convex subset of compact-open topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a locally-compact metric space, $E$ be a Banach space, and equip $C(X,E)$ with the compact-open topology.  Suppose that $Z\subseteq C(X,E)$ is such that $\operatorname{span}(Z)$ is dense in $C(X,E)$.  Then, is $co(Z)\triangleq \left\{\sum_{i=1}^n k_iz_i:\,k_i \in [0,1],\, \sum_{i=1}^n k_i=1,\, z_i \in Z,\, n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$ dense in a non-empty open subset of $C(X,E)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trivial answer first: If $X=\{x\}$ is a singleton and $E=\mathbb R$ then $C(X,E)=\mathbb R$ and the singleton $\{1\}\in \mathbb R$ is a closed convex set with empty interior whose spane is dense.

More interesting is the following: There are many Banach spaces which are *(weakly) comactly generated*, i.e., there is a (weakly) compact absolutely convex set with dense linear span, for example every separable Banach space is compactly generated. But a compact subset of an infinite dimensional Banach space never has interior points (and if a weakly compact set has interior points then the Banach space is reflexive).

Comment: This is interesting, do you happen to have a reference to this latter fact?

Comment: If you mean the remark about reflexivity I don't have a refernce at hand but the proof is easy: If you have an interior point in a weakly compact set it easily follws by translation and scaling that the unit ball is weakly compact which is equivalent to reflexivity as every text book explains.